# Slicing DAT file by Fixed Width Stored in Dict

Tags: python, dataframe, slice

I am having some trouble (been trying this for long time) and still couldn't get solution on my own. I have a dat file that looks like this format:

abc900800007.2

And I have a dict that contains the column name as key and the values corresponding to the fixed width for the DAT file, my dict goes like mydict = {'col1': 3, 'col2': 8, 'col3': 3).

What I want to do is to create a df by combining both item, so slicing the DAT file through the dict value. The df should be like:

col1  col 2    col 3

abc   90080000 7.2

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: does mydict always have 3 items?

Comment: Yes it is, only have single dict with 3 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a possible (but depending on the file size memory intensive) solution is:

```py
data = {'col1':[], 'col2':[], 'col3':[]}
for line in open('file.dat'):
    data['col1'].append(line[:mydict['col1']])
    begin = mydict['col1']
    end = begin + mydict['col2']
    data['col2'].append(line[begin:end])
    begin = end
    end = begin + mydict['col3'] 
    data['col3'].append(line[begin:end])
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # create the DataFrame
del data # delete the auxiliar data
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I just tried your solution but the result that I get is each character goes into column 1 (eg: a = row 1, col1, b = row 2 col1) instead of col1 to be abc

Comment: edit: my stupid mistake, thank you so much for the help!